# Does Flutter supports the android TV?

Tags: flutter

I would like to know whether Flutter supports Android TV. Please provide a suggestion to access the remote key in my application if Flutter supports Android TV.

Answer (score 0):

There is no where mentioned officially about Android TV in flutter website but Android TV Supports play store so you can somehow create app for TV in flutter.
But Google Android Studio (Java/Kotlin) officially supports Android TV.